# UI5 Tooling: Specifying libraries dependencies in ui5.yaml

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

Playing with UI5 Tooling, I see that the **ui5.yaml** config file contains a framework library section, where we supposed to specify UI5 app dependencies, e.g. `sap.m`, `sap.ui.core` etc.:

```yaml
specVersion: "2.5"
type: application
metadata:
    name: com.myApp
framework:
    name: OpenUI5
    version: 1.95.0
    libraries:
        -   name: sap.m
        -   name: sap.ui.core
```

If I understand it correctly, these `libraries` section is used to incorporate these libs into `Component-preload.js`. Is it a correct assumption?

My questions:

1. Should the `framework/libraries` section of **ui5.yaml** be identical to the `sap.ui5/dependencies/libs` one of **manifest.json**?
2. Should I specify this `libraries` section at all in case, if I consume UI5 lib from the CDN?

Comment: I was wondering the same years ago... looks like documentation still lacks some details https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/521.
 i use on CDN, works out of the box without any config.